# Как получить два списка при помощи Stream API?

Tags: java, алгоритм, функции, java-8, java-stream

А именно. Имеется список неких объектов `Cat`:

```
public class Cat {
     LocalDate birthDay;
     int weight;
}
```

При помощи **Stream API** я хочу разбить их на две категории по следующему параметру:
*берём условного `cat1` из списка. Если вес всех котов, которые родились в то же время, что и наш кот, больше 100, добавляем его в карту под ключом false, а если меньше или ровно, то в карту под ключом true.*

На выходе должна получиться карта `Map<Boolean, List<Cat>>`. Для таких вещей в **Stream API** существует метод `partitioningBy()`, но с ним я могу разделять котов только относительно того, удовлетворяет ли их собственный вес условию, а мне надо, чтобы коты разделялись относительно того, удовлетворяет ли сумма веса всех котов, которые родились с рассматриваемым котом, определённому условию.

Объясните, как такое можно сделать:

1. Не используя сторонние коллекции.
2. Не меняя класс.
3. Желательно, без собственной реализации `Collector`.

Comment: ну то есть вам сначала надо замапить ваших котов по дате, и после отдельным шагом для каждой даты переводить котов в множество true или false

Comment: @tym32167, но это разве реально сделать без сторонних коллекций?

Comment: не понял про сторонние коллекции. Вы сначала свои данные превратите в один хешмап, а потом в другой.

Comment: Я в стримах не силен, но скорее всего вам даже первый хешмап не надо делать, а просто воспользоваться `groupingBy` по дате и потом для каждой группы решать как собрать финальный хешмап

Answer (score 0):

Первым шагом подсчитываем общий вес по дням, а уже потом просто разделием всех котов.

```
package com.somepackage;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

class Main {

    @Data
    @Builder
    public static class Cat {
        LocalDate birthDay;
        int weight;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Cat> cats =
                Stream.of(
                        Cat.builder()
                                .birthDay(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1))
                                .weight(100)
                                .build(),
                        Cat.builder()
                                .birthDay(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1))
                                .weight(200)
                                .build(),
                        Cat.builder()
                                .birthDay(LocalDate.now())
                                .weight(50)
                                .build()
                ).collect(toSet());
        Map<LocalDate, Integer> weightByDate =
                cats.stream()
                        .collect(groupingBy(Cat::getBirthDay, summingInt(Cat::getWeight)));
        Map<Boolean, List<Cat>> catsByCondition =
                cats.stream()
                        .collect(partitioningBy(c -> weightByDate.get(c.getBirthDay()) < 100));
        System.out.println(catsByCondition);
    }

}
```

Результат:

```
{false=[Main.Cat(birthDay=2020-09-16, weight=100), Main.Cat(birthDay=2020-09-16, weight=200)], true=[Main.Cat(birthDay=2020-09-17, weight=50)]}
```

Comment: Можно, конечно. Но у вас, к сожалению, получается несколько коллекций. Мне необходимо реализовать алгоритм без использования внешних коллекций (т.е. без коллекций, которые находятся вне пределов стрима, кроме исходной коллекции)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```java
Map<Boolean, List<Cat>> sortedCats = cats.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        cat -> cats
                .stream()
                .filter(cat1 -> cat1.birthDay.equals(cat.birthDay))
                .collect(Collectors.summingInt(o -> o.weight))
                .intValue() > 100
));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Можно ли реализовать такое со сложностью O(N)? У вас, насколько я вижу, получается O(N^2)

Comment: Не знаю.. Возможно можно как-то переписать без использования ссылки на саму коллекцию в группировке, но касаемо сложности я не уверен что она тут N^2. Что там внутри стримов не знаю. Проверил эмпирически на коллекциях рандомных котов от 100 до 10000. В окрестности 100 сортировка заняла в районе 1 мс, в окрестностях 10000 - в район 700 мс. Т.е. рост явно не N^2.